# Arcanist - doing an "arc diff" after a git push

Tags: git, arcanist

Arcanist noob here.

I want to run "arc diff" but the problem is that I already did a "git push" to our remote git repository. Perhaps there is another arc command to see the diff even after a push? Couldn't find such a command in the Arcanist files.

Comment: Do you want just see diff or you want to send review to phabricator after git push?

Comment: thanks, I'd like to be able to review on phabricator